# python global object cache

Tags: python, design-patterns, global-variables, class-design

Little question concerning app architecture:

I have a python script, running as a daemon.

Inside i have many objects, all inheriting from one class (let's name it 'entity')

I have also one main object, let it be 'topsys'

Entities are identified by pair (id, type (= class, roughly)), and they are connected in many wicked ways. They are also created and deleted all the time, and they are need to access other entities.

So, i need a kind of storage, basically dictionary of dictionaries (one for each type), holding all entities.

And the question is, what is better: attach this dictionary to 'topsys' as a object property or to class entity, as a property of the class? I would opt for the second (so entities does not need to know of existence of 'topsys'), but i am not feeling good about using properties directly in classes. Or maybe there is another way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's not enough detail here to be certain of what's best, but in general I'd store the actual object registry as a module-level (global) variable in the top class, and have a method in the base class to access it.

```
_entities = []
class entity(object):
    @staticmethod
    def get_entity_registry(): 
         return _entities
```

Alternatively, hide _entites entirely and expose a few methods, eg. `get_object_by_id`, `register_object`, so you can change the storage of _entities itself more easily later on.

By the way, a tip in case you're not there already: you'll probably want to look into [weakrefs](http://docs.python.org/library/weakref.html) when creating object registries like this.

Comment: it's exactly what i am doing, thanks for confirmation :) - and kudos for weakref, it is exactly what i need

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with using properties on classes. Classes are just objects, too.

In your case, with this little information available, I would go for a class property, too, because not creating dependencies ist great and will be one worry less sometimes later.